# Can Scaling be changed based on inputs?

Tags: pine-script

I have an indicator that I would like to be able to plot both in the chart window and in the lower pane using plotshape.  If it plots in the chart window the plotshape is location.belowbar, if it plots in the lower window the plotshape = 3, location.absolute and I use color changes to show the signals.  I've figured out how to hide the below.bar plotshapes if it's plotted in the lower window, and how to hide the location.absolute if it's plotted in the upper window.

The problem is in the scaling:  If I change the inputs to hide plotshape below.bar and unhide the plotshape with a value of "3", and move the indicator to the lower pane, it STILL uses the price scale from the chart.  The scale doesn't auto adjust.  So if I'm plotting a plotshape in the lower pane with a value of  "3" on chart with SPY the right scale still factors SPY's price @ ~ 280.

I've tried "overlay = true, scale = scale.none/left/right" and no overlay instructions.  Nothing works.  No matter what, the price scale is always factored.

'any help or ideas would be SUPER appreciated!!!!!

// -------------

```
All_Plot_Loc_Upper = if (Plot_Loc == "Chart Window")
    All_Plot_Loc_Upper = 1
else
    na


Plot_Loc_Lower_NPA = if Plot_Loc == "Chart Window"
    na
else
    3

plotshape(DS_Long_PB_HHV > 0 and All_Plot_Loc_Upper == 1, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny) 
plotshape(series = -Plot_Loc_Lower_NPA, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because using `location=location.belowbar` will put the price scale into play, even when plotting `na`. This code replaces the location with something else when not using overlay mode.

When you move the indie to a pane, uncheck the `chartMode` checkmark in *Inputs* and click on the chart; the pane's scale will be correct:

```
//@version=4
study("")
chartMode = input(false)

All_Plot_Loc_Upper = if chartMode
    1
else
    na
Plot_Loc_Lower_NPA = if chartMode
    na
else
    3

plotshape(All_Plot_Loc_Upper, style=shape.triangleup, location=chartMode ? location.belowbar : location.bottom, size=size.tiny) 
plotshape(series = -Plot_Loc_Lower_NPA, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU and everyone else on here who are helping us newbies out!!  I didn't think the solution you offered was even possible!!!  I looked around on Google and pine script reference and found nothing about "chartMode".  Without your help I never would have known about it.  Have a beautiful w/e!!
D.